# What does "numbers = (first, second) + rest" do?

Tags: python

What does `numbers = (first, second) + rest` do?

`(first, second)` is a tuple, so what does it mean to add something to a tuple?

Comment: Is it big deal to try it?

Comment: If `rest` is a tuple too, they are concatenated, otherwise this will probably/should fail at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Although just a guess, it safe to assume rest is also tuple and you add 2 tuples, e.g. something like this

```
first = 1
second = 2
rest = (3, 4, 5)
numbers = (first, second) + rest
print(numbers)
```

output:

```
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```